# How to maintain the position of a table inside a div with two columns and a variable height control?

Tags: html, css

I have the next code:

```
            <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadListBox ID="LstGenero" Width="80px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CheckBoxes="True" Culture="es-ES" DataKeyField="cve_genero" DataSourceID="SDSGenero" DataTextField="descripcion" DataValueField="cve_genero" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                            </telerik:RadListBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadListBox ID="LstMarca" Width="80px" Height="250px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CheckBoxes="True" Culture="es-ES" DataKeyField="cve_marca" DataSourceID="SDSMarca" DataTextField="descripcion" DataValueField="cve_marca" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                            </telerik:RadListBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadListBox ID="LstPresentacion" Width="80px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CheckBoxes="True" Culture="es-ES" DataKeyField="cve_presentacion" DataSourceID="SDSPresentacion" DataTextField="descripcion" DataValueField="cve_presentacion" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                            </telerik:RadListBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <telerik:RadListView ID="RadListView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="12"  DataKeyNames="cve_producto" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholderBusqueda">
        ...
                </telerik:RadListView>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

The first  contains a table with ListBox that always have the same height, the third  have a ListView with a variable height. My problem is the vertical position of the table in the first , it always moves to the center of the listView.

How to maintainthe table always at the top of the td?, regardless of the height change of the listView.

Comment: give `vertical-align:top` to the `td`s

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister. That solved the problema.